# What is the line segment joining midpoints of opposite sides of a quadrilateral called?

Tags: geometry, terminology, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

I'm trying to specify a formula in terms of the line segment joining midpoints of opposite sides of a quadrilateral? Is there an accurate name for them?

Comment: No name... It's the line segment joining midpoints of opposite sides of the quadrilateral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. They are called [bimedians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Bimedians).

(Follow the link for more details.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! I'm surprised I couldn't find that anywhere using Google!